# How to use BigQuery view as source in Cloud data fusion?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am able to use BigQuery table as source and complete the task (screenshot-1) but when i put bigquery view in place of table it throws error(screenshot-2).

**screenshot-1**
[image]

**screenshot-2**
[image: screenshot-2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you are using version 0.14.2 of the Google Cloud Plugin. The support for BigQuery View was added later. You can find the newer version of Google Cloud plugin from the Hub, and you can find Google Cloud Platform. Then on studio, hover over the BigQuery source, click on the **change**, and select the latest version.

Comment: Thank a lot Edwin, Followed your instructions word by word and it worked with 0.14.11 version.

Comment: great to hear that!